# MESHブロックの通知から湿度の値を取り出したい

Tags: python

8月31日に公開されたMESHブロックの通信仕様をもとに、PythonでMESHブロックで検知した温度・湿度の取得を実装しようとしています。公式ドキュメントを参考に実装して、MESHブロック(温度・湿度)から下記の通り、通知を受け取ることはできました。

```
b'\x01\x00\x00\x04\xe9\x00D\x002'
```

温度に関しては、e9なので10進数に変換して233/10で23.3度と正しく取得できているようですが、湿度はDが返ってきました。

MESHアプリのほうで、確認すると湿度50％前後を計測しているので、正しく測定できていると思うのですが、上記の値はどのようにすれば、正しく10進数の値に変換できますでしょうか。

Comment: 使用しているのは「温度・湿度ブロック (MESH-100TH)」ですか?

Comment: 公式の [技術ドキュメント](https://developer.meshprj.com/hc/ja/articles/8286377144729) は参照済みでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

MESHブロックの知識はありませんが単に\x44(68)がDと表示されてるだけではないでしょうか。
以下はPythonの対話モードでの実行結果です

```
>>> b'\x44'
b'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

MESHについては分からないので間違ってるかもだけど
コメントからのドキュメントで [温度・湿度ブロック (MESH-100TH)](https://developer.meshprj.com/hc/ja/articles/8286425847961) の「状態通知」と判断します

```py
from struct import unpack, calcsize
data = b'\x01\x00\x00\x04\xe9\x00D\x002'
print(f"書式 {calcsize('<4BhhB')}, データ {len(data)}")
unpack('<4BhhB', data)
# 書式 9, データ 9
# (1, 0, 0, 4, 233, 68, 50)
```

参考: [struct --- バイト列をパックされたバイナリデータとして解釈する](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/struct.html)